# Why is Hibernate generating a duplicate primary key on my table

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

I am using Hibernate version 4.3.11 with H2 database version 1.3.172

I had this error

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:492)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:197)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:181)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:216)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:334)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:289)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
at com.jthink.songkong.db.SongChangesCache.saveMatchedToRelease(SongChangesCache.java:29)
at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.SongSave.saveSongChangedDetailsToDb(SongSave.java:416)
at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.SongSave.call(SongSave.java:163)
at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.SongSave.call(SongSave.java:73)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.SONGCHANGES(ID)"; SQL statement:
insert into SongChanges (id, field, newValue, originalValue, recNo, reportId, type, version) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-172]
```

I have never seen this error before, my songchanges table use the standard
way to generate primary keys

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer      id;
```

My `Session` is not shared between threads, but there are mutiple threads that could be writing to the songchanges table with their own session but why should that matter ?

My configuration is as follows

```
private static void addEntitiesToConfig(Configuration config) {
    config.addAnnotatedClass(MusicBrainzReleaseWrapper.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(MusicBrainzReleaseGroupWrapper.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(MusicBrainzArtistWrapper.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(DiscogsReleaseWrapper.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(AcoustidWrapper.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(PuidWrapper.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(Song.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(CoverImage.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(CoverArt.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(MatchedToMusicBrainz.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(MatchedToAllMusicGuide.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(MatchedToDiscogs.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(SongProcessed.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(SongChanges.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(DeleteDuplicates.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(AcoustidRecordingIdPair.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(ITunesTrack.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(Report.class);
}

public static Configuration getInitializedConfiguration() {
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.h2.Driver");
    config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:h2:" + Db.DBFOLDER + "/" + Db.DBNAME + ";FILE_LOCK=SOCKET;MVCC=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;CACHE_SIZE=50000");
    config.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
    System.setProperty("h2.bindAddress", InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress().getHostAddress());
    config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "******");
    config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "******");
    config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads", "10");
    config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", "20");
    config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", "200");
    config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", "300");
    config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.maxStatementsPerConnection", "50");
    config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", "3000");
    config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts", "10");
    addEntitiesToConfig(config);
    return config;
}
```

I get a session like this

```
  public static Session beginTransaction() {
        Session hibernateSession = getSession();
        hibernateSession.beginTransaction();
        return hibernateSession;
    }
```

SongChanges class is as follows

```
package com.jthink.songlayer;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Table;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 *
 */

@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo="SongChanges",indexes =
@org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "IDX_SONG_CHANGES_REPORTID_RECNO",
        columnNames = {"reportId", "recNo"})
)
public class SongChanges
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer      id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "IDX_SONG_CHANGES_REPORTID")
    private Integer      reportId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "IDX_SONG_CHANGES_RECNO")
    private Integer      recNo;

    private SongFieldKey field;

    @Column(length = 10000)
    private String       originalValue;

    @Column(length = 10000)
    private String       newValue;

    @Version
    private int version;

    private SongChangeType      type;


    public Integer getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getReportId()
    {
        return reportId;
    }

    public void setReportId(Integer reportId)
    {
        this.reportId = reportId;
    }

    public Integer getRecNo()
    {
        return recNo;
    }

    public void setRecNo(Integer recNo)
    {
        this.recNo = recNo;
    }

    public SongFieldKey getField()
    {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(SongFieldKey field)
    {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public String getOriginalValue()
    {
        return originalValue;
    }

    public void setOriginalValue(String originalValue)
    {
        this.originalValue = originalValue;
    }

    public String getNewValue()
    {
        return newValue;
    }

    public void setNewValue(String newValue)
    {
        this.newValue = newValue;
    }

    public SongChangeType getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(SongChangeType type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you added some data to database manually?

Comment: Why don't you create a sequence?

Comment: You haven't shown the code you're using, in particular what kind of transactional setup you have.

Comment: @Leviand no, no daat added manually

Comment: @chrylis okay I have added my Hibernate config and how I get a session

Comment: @TiagoMussi I dont know, why should I, I thought I was using the standard approach

Comment: Can I see the schema?

Comment: @MauricePerry Ive added the source code of the problematic class (SongChanges). Please note this issue doesn't usually happen, it has just happened once making me think that perhaps an issue with hibernate or h2

Comment: Okay, your Hibernate setup is sending `null` as the ID, which should cause the database to generate it. The most likely case for a collision in this case is that your transaction isolation is set too low. (Note that it looks like you're following a guide that is severely out of date; it should cover the very basics here, but it's already missing best practices.)

Comment: @chrylis ok sounds possible, was the 'here' in your comment meant to be a hyperlink. Im not sure where i set transaction isolation but I hope I can fix this without introducing restrictions to the way it works.

Comment: No hyperlink; I mean that this is a very simple situation so you won't be instructed *too* badly, but it's definitely not up to date. As an example, I use Spring `@Transactional` management everywhere, and I don't know off the top of my head where to programmatically set it in Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that your `id` is not being generated as your can see in you log file the value `null`.

There are plenty of ways to approach this and one of them is creating a sequence.

You can do that by adding the `strategy` to your `@GeneratedValue`. You will have something like that:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SONG_CHANGES_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "SONG_CHANGES_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, name = "SONG_CHANGES_SEQ")
private Integer id;
```

Comment: I use this method for all my Hibernate classes and everything works usually, so why would it generate null in this case, I can see the null reference you refer to but dont understand why it just failed this once.